# Sounds and music not working in one user account

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, audio

On my Mac, in one user account (I use several) I don't get any sound in videos or when playing music.

The system signal sounds (like when turning volume up) are working.

Everything else is normal as I can see. A restart does not fix it. Can I do something about it?

Comment: No sound in video or music regardless of player. System prefs - sound : Default values (I don't see the reason to be any more specific). Volume in middle when ⌥ and click on the loudspeaker icon.

Comment: It seems to me like a dive-routine is not getting loaded, could that be it?

Comment: Yes, now I understand what you mean (ctrl + opt since I'm on macbook pro) that's why I missed it.

Comment: I can verify that it is "internal speakers". All this is very strange.